Software for computing polytopes
As can be inferred from the title, I want to do some computation on the facets representation of the polytopes given the vertices. My advisor recommended me Polymake, which is indeed useful even with thousands of vertices or more, but I noticed that it only exploits single core of my CPU. Thus, I tried to find more software that enable parallel computation.
One example is PANDA, as I tried to run the software, it indeed exploit all cores. Ironically, all cores have full utility, while the computation is far slower than Polymake. Since the paper on PANDA claims that it is faster than Polymake in most cases, because it uses a different algorithm, what could be the reason for this? One possibility is that the structure of my polytope is weird that the software is not good at solving it. Could it be also possible be the problem of the C++ version? I am definitely using a newer C++: while it is compatible, could it be slower than older versions?
Aside from this question on PANDA, I wonder if the community has any other suggestions for software. I noticed PORTA, which was designed by the same group as PANDA, but it does not seem to enable parallel computing, would it be worth a try?
Thank you all in advance!

The common C++ compilers should have an option to compile with a specific standard, for example g++ -std=c++11 your_file.cpp -o your_program to compile with the C11 standard, but this should affect only compile time, not necessarily run time.

Cross-posted here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/472551/software-for-computing-polytopes

Convex polytopes?
